Changing User Email Address in Microsoft Entra External ID
I'm looking for a way to update the email address of a user in Microsoft Entra External ID in my external tenant that registered with Email/Password.
I came across documentation for resetting redemption status for a guest user, but this does not apply to external tenants.
Is there a way to update the email address (issuerAssignedId) for a user after initial creation in Entra External ID?

External ID uses the same Graph API commands as B2C.
You can update the identity.
"Updating the identities property requires the User.ManageIdentities.All permission. Also, adding a B2C local account to an existing user object is not allowed, unless the user object already contains a local account identity".
Note that the existing Identity has to contain a local account and you have to update the whole Identity array.
Since you are changing the user Identity, they will not be able to login with their previous one.

Note: I have a post on this - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/working-with-user-attributes-using-entra-external-id-for-customers-0eed9df92e2a
